# how to resolve ssh key rejection while deploying 1st Rails3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, public-key-encryption, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy a Rails3 application, for the 1st time, to Dreamhost using Git & Capistrano. Using Dreamhost's Capistrano setup instructions. Down to one last error:

```
Cap deploy:check => looks good.
Cap deploy:setup => looks good.
```

However, Cap deploy:cold  => fails:

```
** [alvarez.dreamhost.com :: out] Permission denied (publickey).
** [alvarez.dreamhost.com :: out] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My config/deploy.rb file contains, among other variables,

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/home/bubby/.ssh/id_rsa)        
set :chmod755, "app config db lib public vendor script script/* public/disp*"
set :use_sudo, false
```

Public key setup completed on home PC. (Ubuntu.) Working with GitHub repository.

Have copied public key to domain directory per DH's instructions.

Any suggestions? Reaching the limit of DH's help capabilities. Thanks.

Comment: From out of the blue: Are you using git@github.com:... in your deploy.rb for the repo url?

Comment: correct @iltempo!    set :repository,  "git@github.com:<user>/<reponame>.git"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set the repository url to the read-only version:

`set :repository, "https://github.com/bjpcjp/catalog.git"`

Otherwise git is trying to use your private ssh key to authenticate against GitHub. This fails on server unless you take additional actions.

Comment: Done. Results: [bubby@ubuntu:~/<url>] $ cap deploy:cold
  * executing `deploy:cold'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote https://github.com:<user>.<reponame>.git master"

fatal: https://github.com:<user>/<reponame>.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Git update-server-info executed on local machine; no change in results.

Comment: Please try to do a `cap deploy:setup` again first.

Comment: Seems still be using the old url. Try to remove the directories from your server and start again with deploy:setup and deploy:cold.

Comment: done. (FTP'd into Dreamhost and cleaned out directory. Exited to local machine.)

    cap deploy:setup => done.
    cap deploy:cold => fails for same result ("git ls-remote github.com:<user>.<reponame>.git master" fatal: <same>/info/refs not found.")